# numpy.polyfit vs numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit

Tags: python, numpy

Why do [`numpy.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) and [`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html)
produce different plots in the test below?

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
y = 5 * x + 10 + (np.random.random(len(x)) - 0.5) * 5

plt.scatter(x, y,marker='.', label='Data for regression')
plt.plot(x, np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 1))(x), label='numpy.polyfit')
plt.plot(x, np.poly1d(polyfit(x, y, 1))(x), label='polynomial.polyfit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

At first glance, the documentation seems to indicate they should give the same result -

> `numpy.polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)`
>   
>   Least squares polynomial fit.
>   
>   Fit a polynomial `p(x) = p[0] * x**deg + ... + p[deg]` of degree *deg* to points *(x, y)*. Returns a vector of coefficients *p* that minimises the squared error in the order *deg, deg-1, … 0*.

and

> `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond=None, full=False, w=None)`
>   
>   Least-squares fit of a polynomial to data.
>   
>   Return the coefficients of a polynomial of degree deg that is the least squares fit to the data values y given at points x. If y is 1-D the returned coefficients will also be 1-D. If y is 2-D multiple fits are done, one for each column of y, and the resulting coefficients are stored in the corresponding columns of a 2-D return. The fitted polynomial(s) are in the form
>   
>   
>   *p(x) = c<sub>0</sub> + c<sub>1</sub> * x + ... + c<sub>n</sub> * x<sup>n</sup>*

But the difference is in the order of coefficients returned from the two methods, at least for the use case in question.

- `numpy.polyfit` returns the coefficients in *descending* order of degree, according to the generation equation

  *p(x) = c<sub>n</sub> * x<sup>n</sup> + c<sub>(n-1)</sub> * x<sup>(n-1)</sup> + ... + c<sub>1</sub> * x + c<sub>0</sub>*
- `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit` returns the coefficients in *ascending* order of degree, according to the generation equation

  *p(x) = c<sub>0</sub> + c<sub>1</sub> * x + ... + c<sub>(n-1)</sub> * x<sup>(n-1)</sup> + c<sub>n</sub> * x<sup>n</sup>*

though mathematically identical, those two equations are not the same in `ndarray` representation. This might be obfuscated by the use of different notations in the documentation. For demonstration, consider the following

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
y = x**2 + 5 * x + 10

print(np.polyfit(x, y, 2))
print(np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 2))
```

```
[ 1.  5. 10.]
[10.  5.  1.]
```

Both methods get the same result, but in opposite order, the former being what [`np.poly1d()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) expects,

```py
print(np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 2)))
print(np.poly1d(np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 2)))
```

```
   2
1 x + 5 x + 10
    2
10 x + 5 x + 1
```

and the latter being what the [`np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial) constructor expects.,

```py
print(np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial(np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 2)))
print(np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial(np.polyfit(x, y, 2)))
```

```
poly([10.  5.  1.])  # 10 + 5 * x + 1 * x**2
poly([ 1.  5. 10.])  # 1 + 5 * x + 10 * x**2
```

[Flipping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) the result from `np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit` before passing it to `poly1d()` or using a `np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial` will produce the expected result:

[image: Matching output]