# Curve fitting with known coefficients in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, data-science, curve-fitting

I tried using Numpy, Scipy and Scikitlearn, but couldn't find what I need in any of them, basically I need to fit a curve to a dataset, but restricting some of the coefficients to known values, I found how to do it in MATLAB, using `fittype`, but couldn't do it in python.

In my case I have a dataset of X and Y and I need to find the best fitting curve, I know it's a polynomial of second degree (ax^2 + bx + c) and I know it's values of b and c, so I just needed it to find the value of a.

The solution I found in MATLAB was https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/216688-constraining-polyfit-with-known-coefficients which is the same problem as mine, but with the difference that their polynomial was of degree 5th, how could I do something similar in python?

To add some info: I need to fit a curve to a dataset, so things like scipy.optimize.curve_fit that expects a function won't work (at least as far as I tried).

Comment: You definitively should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69573962/803359) SO post

Comment: I think their problem is a bit different, because they know only the intercept coefficient, while mine is fitting to a "almost all known function", even though I think it isn't the same problem I'll be sure to check it out just to be sure

Comment: well, if you want to fit `a * x**2 + b * x + c`, but `b` and `c` are known, you just subtract that information of your `y`-values `ys = y - b * x - c ` and fit `a * x**2` to that data, e.g. via `Polinomial.fit( ..., deg=[2] )

Comment: Note, at that point `curve_fit` would work fine. However, this is a linear fit and `curve_fit, technically, is for non-linear fits, so it is somehow not the right tool for the job. But this more a purist rather than a practical point of view

Comment: @mikuszefski The problem is my b value is 0, so the sub will not make a difference, and the Poly fit will try to guess it anyway.

Comment: No, not with `deg=[2]`, check the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tools you have available usually expect functions only inputting their parameters (`a` being the only unknown in your case), or inputting their parameters and some data (`a`, `x`, and `y` in your case).

Scipy's curve-fit handles that use-case just fine, so long as we hand it a function that it understands. It expects `x` first and all your parameters as the remaining arguments:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

b = 0
c = 0
def f(x, a):
    return c+x*(b+x*a)

x = np.linspace(-5, 5)
y = x**2

# params == [1.]
params, _ = curve_fit(f, x, y)
```

Alternatively you can reach for your favorite minimization routine. The difference here is that you manually construct the error function so that it *only* inputs the parameters you care about, and then you don't need to provide that data to scipy.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

b = 0
c = 0

x = np.linspace(-5, 5)
y = x**2

def error(a):
    prediction = c+x*(b+x*a)
    return np.linalg.norm(prediction-y)/len(prediction)**.5

result = minimize(error, np.array([42.]))
assert result.success

# params == [1.]
params = result.x
```

I don't think scipy has a partially applied polynomial fit function built-in, but you could use either of the above ideas to easily build one yourself if you do that kind of thing a lot.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def polyfit(coefs, x, y):
    # build a mapping from null coefficient locations to locations in the function
    # coefficients we're passing to curve_fit
    # 
    # idx[j]==i means that unknown_coefs[i] belongs in coefs[j]
    _tmp = [i for i,c in enumerate(coefs) if c is None]
    idx = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(_tmp)}

    def f(x, *unknown_coefs):
        # create the entire polynomial's coefficients by filling in the unknown
        # values in the right places, using the aforementioned mapping
        p = [(unknown_coefs[idx[i]] if c is None else c) for i,c in enumerate(coefs)]
        return np.polyval(p, x)
    
    # we're passing an initial value just so that scipy knows how many parameters
    # to use
    params, _ = curve_fit(f, x, y, np.zeros((sum(c is None for c in coefs),)))

    # return all the polynomial's coefficients, not just the few we just discovered
    return np.array([(params[idx[i]] if c is None else c) for i,c in enumerate(coefs)])

x = np.linspace(-5, 5)
y = x**2

# (unknown)x^2 + 1x + 0
# params == [1, 0, 0.]
params = fit([None, 0, 0], x, y)
```

Similar features exist in nearly every mainstream scientific library; you just might need to reshape your problem a bit to frame it in terms of the available primitives.

Comment: I think you made me realize what I needed all along was the curve_fit I thought wouldn't work, I'm gonna be sure to try it out the way you showed because it really looks like it works, but I'm really a beginner on this so after the second code block I didn't understand anything, was it just a more advanced/precise way of doing the same thing? Because if it is I'll stick to the easier a bit less precise, if it isn't than do you have any link to a more detailed break down of the topic? In the overall thanks.

Comment: The 3 code blocks are different ways to do the same thing. The first uses curve_fit. The second uses minimize (slightly more complicated, but it can be used in more situations than just fitting curves to data). The third creates a function `polyfit` that automagically handles mixed known/unknown polynomial coefficients (using `None` to represent coefficients you don't know), in case you happen to be doing a lot of this kind of thing.

Comment: ...maybe `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial` for block 4?

Comment: I suppose we shouldn't use deprecated code ;) I'll update that eventually, or feel free to edit the post if you'd like.